# table look confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this problem. i think it is simple but i just couldn't get it right. 
Im building graph and table using gruff.I have a x axis scaled from month 01 to 12
The data shud hv bn plotted in month 09 and 10 but it is plotted to month 08 and 10.

```
def stat1
  @yeara = params[:year]
  @games = Games.find(:all)
  g = Gruff::StackedBar.new('800x450')
  g.theme = {
    :colors => ['#138F6A','#330000','#ff6600', '#3bb000', '#1e90ff', '#efba00', '#0aaafd'],
    :marker_color => '#aaa',
    :background_colors => ['#eaeaea', '#fff']
  }
  g.hide_title = true

  @dr = Game.count(:all, :conditions=> ["game_id= ? and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y')= ?",1,@yeara], :group => "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m')", :order =>"date ASC")
  @df = Game.count(:all, :conditions=> ["game_id= ? and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') = ?",2,@yeara], :group => "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m')", :order =>"date ASC")
# all 12 month a year      
   @full = Hash["01",0,"02",0,"03",0,"04",0,"05",0,"06",0,"07",0,"08",0,"09",0,"10",0,"11",0,"12",0]      
  year = (@dr.keys |@df.keys|@full.keys).sort
  @keys = Hash[*year.collect {|v| [year.index(v),v.to_s] }.flatten]

# Plot data to table
  @dfdr = Array.new
  @dfdr <<  @keys.collect {|k,v| @df[v].nil? ? 0 : @df[v]}
  @dfdr <<  @keys.collect {|k,v| @dr[v].nil? ? 0 : @dr[v]}

# Plot data to graph
  g.data("Adam", @keys.collect {|k,v| @dr[v].nil? ? 0 : @dr[v]}) 
  g.data("Eve", @keys.collect {|k,v| @df[v].nil? ? 0 : @df[v]})
  g.labels = @keys

  g.write("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/game.png")  
  render(:layout => false)
```

here are some explanation
the output for

```
@dr = Game.count(:all, :conditions=> ["game_id= ? and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y')= ?",1,@yeara], :group => "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m')", :order =>"date ASC")
```

=> [["09",3],["10",1]

```
@df = Game.count(:all, :conditions=> ["game_id= ? and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') = ?",2,@yeara], :group => "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m')", :order =>"date ASC")
```

=> [["10",2]]

trying to trace where went wrong..but ran out of idea.
please point something out to me.wish i could paste the graph but im not eligible yet say stackoverflow. ;)

thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it.

```
@keys.collect {|k,v| @df[v].nil? ? 0 : @df[v]
```

the @keys are in unsorted order.So simply sort it first.

```
@keys.sort.collect {|k,v| @df[v].nil? ? 0 : @df[v]
```

Thank you all. :))))) Sorry if anything. ;)